# First time using scp -r before and I keep getting an error "Host Key verification error"

Tags: bash, file-transfer, scp

I've never used the bash language before (is scp -r part of bash?) and there's a C++ Xcode file I want to copy to a different IDE (more specifically for a robot controller). That C++ file is in a folder, and I heard that you use `scp -r` for folders? So I tried using that: `scp -r Desktop/oroni-club/gyro.cpp root@192.168.124.1:"[path]"`

The host key is the IP address of the controller, and I'm not quite sure what `"[path]"` is, someone just told me to use that.

I also keep getting this error: `Host key verification failed.
lost connection`, and it doesn't end up copying the C++ file to the other IDE.

I'm not sure what to do and how to copy a C++ file to this other non C++ IDE (this one only offers C and Python, but you can still add a C++ file using bash through the terminal), I'm completely new to this...

Comment: BTW, you want to replace [path] with the actual path on the remote server's filesystem where you want the file to be placed. By default the path is relative to the home directory of the account you're connecting to on the server. In your example, that's the root (super user) account, whose home directory might be something like `/home/root` or `/var/root` depending on the OS of the target host and how it's configured.

Answer (score 0):

The host key is an RSA (or DSA, or Elliptic Curve) public key by which the ssh/scp server (the one running sshd) authenticates itself to your ssh/scp client, so you know you're not connecting to an impostor server. Your ssh/scp client will ask you, the first time you connect to a new server, if you want to accept the offered host key. If you accept it, it's stored in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` so it can be used to authenticate that host in the future.

If you're sure you're not dealing with a Man-in-the-Middle attack or other impostor, you can clear out the host key you'd previously cached for that hostname or IP address by editing `~/.ssh/known_hosts` to remove the line for that host, or you can use `ssh-keygen -R hostname` to remove it. If you always connect by IP address, then use that IP address instead of a hostname as your argument to `ssh-keygen -R …`.